# Google Analytics Management API - batch request return "Quota Error: Rate limit for writes exceeded"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, limits, quota, batch-request

I have server-side app which connect to [GA Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/) with user credentials after oAuth login. It creates predefined 
[Remarketing Audiences](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/remarketingAudience) (can be over 30 audiences). I am sending it in [batch request](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/batching) because of [API requests limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas).

**The Problem**

Some of audiences are successfully created, but some of them return **Quota Error: Rate limit for writes exceeded.** Why? It has been sent in ONE request...

Any suggest highly appreciated.

## EDIT

I have noticed that when I send batch request with only 4 inserts of audience it successfully pass. I have chunked my batch request to batches of four requests and everything is fine, but it is hack and not satisfying solution... :-/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#write_requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting the limits, all the requests you put into one batch request count as an individual request. See the [limits and quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#write_requests).

Comment: That's the reason... Thank you very much.